# how can we store client ip address to database by overwritten Kubernetes IP Address?

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, ip-address

I deployed `node.js` app to `kubernetes` and storing IP address of user to database from `node.js` it is always storing `kubernates ip`.

Getting IP address in `node.js` `const IP = req.headers["x-forwarded-for"] || req.connection.remoteAddress;`

In yaml file, I added `externalTrafficPolicy: Local`

Not sure it will work or not.